# Get records using left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as given below

```
    Table A                Table B             Table C              
  =============          ==============        =========
    Id    Name           Id   AId  CId         Id   Name 
    1     A              1    1    1           1    x
    2     B              2    1    1           2    y
    3     C              3    2    1           3    z 
    4     D              4    2    3           4    w
    5     E              5    3    2           5    v
```

Now I want all the records of Table A with matching Id column CId from Table B where CId = 1.

So the output should be like below :

```
Id Name CId
1   A   1 
2   B   1
3   C   1
4   D   Null
5   E   Null
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why do you have/allow duplicates in TableB?  AId(1) maps to CId(1) twice.  Is this correct, or a data cleanliness issues?  If it's the latter, put in constraints, etc, to prevent the data from becoming dirty.  (Such as a unique constraint over those two fields.)

Comment: Is it correct that your output shows `3 C 1`, even though table B doesn't have a record mapping AId(3) to CId(1)?

Comment: is the output you have posted correct?  It seems like the table data doesn't match the requested output.

Comment: No, the data given in table is correct. Table B might contains duplicate records. I want all the records from Table A. If Table B contains CId = 1 with AId then CId should display 1 else Null or zero or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
SELECT
A.Id,
A.Name,
CASE B.CId WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS CId
FROM
A LEFT JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

<s>This is not about LEFT JOINing. You could as well do it with an INNER JOIN. When you don't want the 3 and 2 of column CId to appear you would still have to filter with WHERE and therefore the rows with Id 4 and 5 would not appear, which is not what you want.</s>

**EDIT:**

Given this test data:

```
create table A (Id int, Name varchar(5));
insert into A values 
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(4, 'D'),
(5, 'E');

create table B (Id int, AId int, CId int);
insert into B values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,1),
(4,2,3),
(5,3,2);
```

my query does **not** give a cartesian product. Read and try before downvoting. Anyway, it was not clear to me what you want to achieve, now I've joined on AId column and with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.Id,
A.Name
, CASE 
WHEN B.CId > 1 THEN 1 
WHEN B.CId = 1 THEN 1
ELSE NULL END AS CId
FROM
A LEFT JOIN B ON A.Id = B.AId
```

and it also gives the right output, like the first before. If this is still not what you want, your test data is wrong or I absolutely don't get it.

Comment: It gives a Cartesian product. I want distinct records from table A

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.Name, TableB.CId
FROM TableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.CId 
WHERE TableB.CId = 1
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
The output you desired, can be achieved if you match TableA's ID column with TableB's ID column, **NOT TableB's CId column**. Try below which I tested in my pc and gives thee similar output you needed.

```
select TableA.Id, TableA.Name, TableB.CId  
from TableA 
left outer join TableB on TableA.Id = TableB.Id 
and TableB.CId in 
(
select TableB.CId  
from TableB 
left outer join TableC on TableB.CId = TableC.Id 
WHERE TableB.CId = 1 
) 
group by TableA.Id, TableA.Name, TableB.CId
```

Please inform if I guess it right. Check the column names.

Comment: It gives a Cartesian product. I want distinct records from table A